# Strange behaviour of output

Tags: c

I am completely stuck, in this code, This code is intended to
 **Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.**
I have Written Code For this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
  unsigned long long int mul = 1, temp = 0, reverse = 0, pelindromenum=0;
  int i, j;
   for (i=100;i <=999;i++)
   {
     for(j=i;j<=999;j++)
     {
       mul = i*j;
       temp = mul;
         while (temp != 0)
         {
          reverse = reverse * 10;
          reverse = reverse + temp%10;
          temp = temp/10;
         }
         if (reverse == mul)
         {
           if (pelindromenum <= mul)
        {
            pelindromenum = mul;
            }
         } 
       }  
    }
   printf ("%llu", pelindromenum); 
 }
```

It is giving outut 0. I am not able to understand why it's giving 0, I go through code many times but i am not able to find any issue please help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: `int main(void)` ... `return 0;` please ^^

Comment: welcome to [so], which is a forum about programming questions rather than a place to debug your source code. you might want to read the excellent [How-to debug small programs](ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not resetting `reverse` inside the loop. So it's garbage after the first iteration.

Add `reverse = 0;` before the `while (temp!=0)` block.

Answer (score 1):

You never reset `reverse` to 0 after you calculated the first, so you never detect any palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying by 0 right in the middle of your code, that'll be it.

Comment: Looks like [problem 4 from Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=4) to me.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yaa, this is problem 4 from Project Euler

Answer (score 0):

Also you don't actually initialise `pelindromenum` to zero.

```
unsigned long long int mul = 1, temp = 0, reverse = 0, pelindromenum;=0
```